# Adding a scroll event to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid defined as follows as part of a UserControl:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"                                       
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode ="Standard"
              EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
             ItemsSource ="{Binding}" Block.TextAlignment="Center"
             AlternatingRowBackground="#F1F1F1" RowBackground="White"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" FrozenColumnCount="1"
               GridLinesVisibility="None" >
    </DataGrid>
```

I'd like to add an event on when the user drags horizontally on the DataGrid, it updates another chart I have.  Can someone point me in the direction to get this started?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'drags horizontally'? Do you mean scrolls horizontally?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to find out when the user has scrolled the `DataGrid` Horizontally. This can be done with the attached event `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged`.

Xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtGrid"
          ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="dtGrid_ScrollChanged"
          ... />
```

Code behind

```
private void dtGrid_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HorizontalChange != 0)
    {
        // Do stuff..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If by 'drags horizontally' you mean 'scrolls horizontally' then you can use the `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` event. The `ScrollChangedEventArgs` contain properties such as `HorizontalOffset` and `HorizontalChange`.